# City field is a drop down box for my default country and I cant fill it out or choose anything

Tags: customer-account, customer-attribute, countries

The City field on the registration form turns into an empty dropdown box instead of a text box, only for my default country. For all other countries, it shows as a text box.

I cannot fill it out or select anything. So users cannot register or purchase anything.

Comment: Do you have any extension for your store?
It seems your extenstion do not work correctly

Comment: sIiiS: Do you have any extension for your store? It seems your extenstion do not work correctly

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have a Javascript error that gets in the way of your browser rendering the drop down properly. Check your console in developer tools for any signs of it and fix the issue.

You can also try revert your custom theme back to the default theme as well. This will allow you to close-in on the root cause more easily.

[Running a recursive diff](https://jasonplayne.com/linux/handy-linux-tips-diff-recursive-compare-on-folders) against a stock Magento 1.7.0.2 might help you out as well.

Comment: The erros occur in all templates, default included. Can it be it has something to do with the language pack installed?

Comment: What's the error? It's likely that there is a Javascript library conflict (most often it's jQuery).

Comment: The error is an empty dropdown box to which I cannot write anything or make a selection.

Comment: <div class="field">
<label class="required" for="city">
<div class="input-box">
<select id="city_id" name="city_id"></select>
<input id="city" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" name="city" value="" title="Cidade" style="display: none;">
</div>
</div>